# Conditional probability of a stochastic procedure

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

I don't have a specific problem I need an answer for. I have a curiosity on how to find the conditional probability of a stochastic process.

Let's say the random process $X(t)$ is wide sense stationary Gaussian with mean and variance as known parameters. How would one calculate the probability $\mathbb{P}( X(t_1) < x | X_t=y )$?.

I cannot seem to find anything out there to answer this question.

Comment: What is $X_t$?  If it is some random value on the $t$-th selection, well, by the nature of stochastic independence it does not affect the probability.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is the crux of my issue. In a stochastic process; are different realizations of the random variable $X(t_i)$ necessarily independent for all $i$ regardless of stationary? I thought that if $X(t)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is wide sense stationary then the realizations are not independent. Am I incorrect?

Comment: You seem to think "wide sense stationary" is a meaningful term.  What does "wide sense" mean to you?

Comment: My understanding is that if we look at two realizations that the PDF is the same. I know that the mean does not change with time.